# client certificate authentication with HTML5 + jQuery frontend and REST backend

Tags: jquery, rest, authentication, servlets, x509certificate

We have a HTML5 + jQuery website, deployed on Apache Http. In short, displayed data is obtained by calling REST services on the backend, deployed on Apache Tomcat. User authenticates herself with user/password to those services, and gets an authorization token back, which is stored as a cookie, to use it in further calls.

I am trying to figure out how to integrate client certificate authentication (X509) in this scenario, as an additional authentication method besides user/password.

What I am thinking is of redirecting the browser to some ssl enabled servlet, request and read the client certificate information, authenticate it, and redirect back to the website with an established session (a token that entitles the client to call backend services through the website). I am not sure how I could somehow keep the user session between these two different components and technologies (if possible).

Any tips, guidance, references, different approaches on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess I could just redirect the user back to the website after authentication takes place, and pass a sessionid through a GET parameter, to be captured by jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

> In short, displayed data is obtained by calling REST services on the
>   backend, deployed on Apache Tomcat. User authenticates herself with
>   user/password to those services, and gets an authorization token back,
>   which is stored as a cookie, to use it in further calls.

This violates the [stateless constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3), so it is not REST. You have to maintain the sessions on the client side, and send the username and password with every (encrypted HTTPS) request.